# Subplot charts plotted within a loop very squashed

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe with ~120 features that I would like to examine by year. I am plotting each feature, x = year, y = feature value within a loop. Whilst these plot successfully, the charts are illegible as they are totally squashed.

I have tried using plt.tight_layout() and adjusting the figure size using plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] but sadly to no avail

```
for i in range(len(roll_df.columns)):
  plt.subplot(len(roll_df.columns), 1, i+1)
  name = roll_df.columns[i]
  plt.plot(roll_df[name])
  plt.title(name, y=0)
  plt.yticks([])
  plt.xticks([])
  plt.tight_layout()
  plt.show()
```

The loop runs but all plots are so squashed on the y-axis as to become illegible:

[image: plot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matplotlib will not automatically adjust the size of your figure. So if you add more subplots below each other, it will split the available space instead of extending the figure. That's why your y axes are so narrow.

You could try to define the figure size beforehand, or determine the figure size based on how many subplots you have:

```
n_plots = roll_df.shape[1]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_plots, 1, figsize=(8, 4 * n_plots), tight_layout=True)

# Then your usual part, but plot on the created axes
for i in range(n_plots):
  name = roll_df.columns[i]
  axes[i].plot(roll_df[name])
  axes[i].title(name, y=0)
  axes[i].yticks([])
  axes[i].xticks([])

plt.show()
```

Comment: If you have multiple rows you need to make the *height*  of the figure dependent on the number of rows. If you have multiple columns, you need to make the *width* of the figure dependent on that number.

Comment: oh yeah, mixed up w and h there, was in a hurry. fixed now. Now that I saw it - kinda counter intuitive, that arrays are indexed (row, column) but figsize is (width, height).

Comment: In general x is horizontal, y is vertical, and x comes first (like `plt.plot(x,y)`). To let array's horizontal dimension denote x, it is however necessary that the array's first dimension is y, this is also useful to maintain the similarity to python lists (`array[i,j] == list[i][j]`). What's unintuitive for me is rather that `subplots(nrows, ncols)` is not `subplots(ncols, nrows)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help here; Unfortunately this threw multiple errors (I have fixed the first): '1. Int object is not iterarable so should be in range(len(roll_df.columns)) but now facing a 'text' object is not callable?

Comment: Try to use `range(df.shape[1])`. Shape outputs `(number of rows, number of columns)` so shape[1] is the number of columns you have. To get the name you can ten use `df.columns[i]`.